# r- install package returned non-zero exit status warning

Tags: r

I am trying to install gdeltr2 in r but I keep getting an error. I got the following error:Downloading GitHub repo abresler/gdeltr2@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\pales\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpI36nL8\remotes14045d19d07\abresler-gdeltr2-1110b37/DESCRIPTION' ...

- preparing 'gdeltr2': (1.5s)
  √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
- checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
- checking for empty or unneeded directories
  Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
- building 'gdeltr2_0.3.1193.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pales/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'gdeltr2' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::last' by 'dplyr::last' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::first' by 'dplyr::first' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::between' by 'dplyr::between' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'curl::handle_reset' by 'httr::handle_reset' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::month' by 'lubridate::month' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::hour' by 'lubridate::hour' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::quarter' by 'lubridate::quarter' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::week' by 'lubridate::week' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::year' by 'lubridate::year' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::wday' by 'lubridate::wday' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::second' by 'lubridate::second' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::minute' by 'lubridate::minute' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::mday' by 'lubridate::mday' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::yday' by 'lubridate::yday' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::isoweek' by 'lubridate::isoweek' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'httr::timeout' by 'memoise::timeout' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'jsonlite::flatten' by 'purrr::flatten' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'data.table::transpose' by 'purrr::transpose' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Warning: replacing previous import 'curl::parse_date' by 'readr::parse_date' when loading 'gdeltr2'
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  there is no package called 'readxl'
  Calls:  ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gdeltr2'
- removing 'C:/Users/pales/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/gdeltr2'
  Warning message:
  In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/pales/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpI36nL8/file14046e31359/gdeltr2_0.3.1193.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status.
  How can I get around this?

Comment: What is the full output from the `install.packages()` command. I assume this is Windows. What R version are you running?

Comment: devtools::install_github("abresler/gdeltr2"). I am running R 4.1.2.

Comment: Usually, a few lines up from the "non-zero" line will be more specific indications of what went wrong. Please paste all lines into your question returned in the console after the execution of `install_github()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by installing readxl. One of the warnings states that  there is no package called 'readxl'